# SQL Server Split Row based Subtraction value

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I'm not sure whether my question is correct or not, but i want to generate output based below input

[image: Input data]

then split the data based on karton quantity. Below is the output.

Is it possible to make this happen using SQL? Its like unpivot the quantity based on

karton quantity.

[image: Output]

or output like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with T as(
    select *, 1 as RNum, Quantity/Karton Split 
    from tbl

    union all

    select 
        T.Num, T.Quantity-T.Karton, T.Karton, T.RNum+1, T.Split 
    from 
        T join tbl T1 on T.Num=T1.Num 
    where 
        T.Split>=1 and T.Quantity-T.Karton>0
)
select Num, Quantity, Karton from T  order by Num, Quantity Desc
```

Fiddle Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cccfdb5d2d9daf634886cede6866fb2d)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the first time I'm using 'With' function in SQL. Will start learning it day by day.

Comment: I have one question, I have created long query with multiple table join together under single object, then when I tried to join under 'T join tbl T1 on T.Num=T1.Num ' this one, its showing Invalid Object name 'tbl'. May I know the reasons? @TechDo

Comment: `tbl` is the physical table where `Quantity, Karton` etc. are store. So re-name it with the table name of yours.

Comment: Okay. How about this condition, `with T as
(
select *, 1 as RNum, Quantity/Karton Split from

(Select a1.No, a1.Quantity, a1.Karton from
(select No, Quantity from tableA) as a1
left join
(Select No, Karton from tableB) as a2 on a1.No = a2.No) as TableC

union all

select T.No, T.Quantity-T.Karton, T.Karton, T.RNum + 1, T.Split

from 
 T join TableC T1 on T.t_orno = T1.t_orno
where
 T.Split >= 1 and T.t_qoor - T.Karton > 0

) Select * from T` Sorry I don't know how to put query in Comment @TechDo

Comment: I don't feel like the logic behind the query is correct, coz in the first select u r using tableA and tableB. But in the select after union all its tableC. Can u plz add these tables and data in https://dbfiddle.uk/?

Comment: sure [link] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3b2182759a7e6ce56be66abbdfc88912) @TechDo

Comment: Plz check the query: 
`;with T as(

 select a.*, b.Karton, 1 as RNum, Quantity/Karton Split  
 from tableA a join tableB b on a.Num=b.Num
 
 union all

 select 
  T.Num, T.Quantity-T.Karton, T.Karton, T.RNum+1, T.Split 
 from 
  tableA a join tableB b on a.Num=b.Num join T on T.Num=a.Num
 where 
  T.Split>=1 and T.Quantity-T.Karton>0
)
select Num, Quantity, Karton from T  
order by Num, Quantity Desc`
Fiddler https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e9ed0f06b3c83e3bb22a1241db037aa3

Answer (score 1):

Create number table

```
INSERT INTO tblNumber
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [N]
FROM dbo.syscolumns tb1,dbo.syscolumns tb2
```

Then,

```
CREATE TABLE #RealTable ( 
    NOs VARCHAR(5),
    Quantity int,
    Karton int)

  INSERT INTO #RealTable VALUES 
    ('A', 5000, 1000),
    ('B', 15000, 5000),
    ('C', 25000, 5000)


;with CTE1 as
(
select c.*,cd.number as Seq
from tblnumber cd, #RealTable c
where cd.number<=(Quantity/Karton)
)

select NOs,Quantity-(karton*(seq-1)) as Quantity
,Karton,Seq from CTE1 c

drop table #RealTable
```

As per your sample data  `CROSS JOIN` execute for  only require number of rows so it won't hurt performance.

So it is important to know your real table and real sample data.If it execute more than what is require then it may hurt performance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use GROUP BY command in SQL

Comment: you can find some suitable example in this link:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your respond. But this is not what im looking for.